# Keep getting { throw new Error('Invalid API Key and/or API Secret. Use dotenv or constructor params.');}

Tags: key, dotenv, xrp

Here is what I get in response to submitting a node command with the deploy-commands.js file:

```
PS C:\Users\socia> node "C:\Users\socia\Desktop\XRPL-DEXBot-main\deploy-commands.js"
C:\Users\socia\node_modules\xumm-sdk\dist\src\Meta.js:51
                throw new Error('Invalid API Key and/or API Secret. Use dotenv or constructor params.');
Error: Invalid API Key and/or API Secret. Use dotenv or constructor params.
    at new Meta (C:\Users\socia\node_modules\xumm-sdk\dist\src\Meta.js:51:23)
    at new XummSdk (C:\Users\socia\node_modules\xumm-sdk\dist\src\index.js:25:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\socia\Desktop\XRPL-DEXBot-main\Utilities.js:8:14)
```

Comment: throw new Error('Invalid API Key and/or API Secret. Use dotenv or constructor params.'); Error: Invalid API Key and/or API Secret.

Comment: But when i check the Xumm Dev console the key and secret match so im confused at why it isnt going through and i have my bot and application.command setting in my Oauth2 settings